# EF 4.1 Database first. "EntityType <Entity> has no key defined."

Tags: entity-framework-4, edmx

I have created a VS 2010, .Net 4, MVC 4 application with Entity Framework 4.1 and MS SQL Server 2008.

The application is split into an MVC web project, a services project and a number of entities projects. Each entity project contains an edmx file and a context. The edmx files have been generated from the database, not code first.

My application compiles and runs successfully until I access a page which references one specific edmx file then I get the errors:

```
System.Data.Edm.EdmEntityType: : EntityType '<Entity>' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
```

and

```
System.Data.Edm.EdmEntitySet: EntityType: EntitySet <Entity>s is based on type <Entity> that has no keys defined.
```

The edmx contains 22 tables and I get this message for 8 of them.

The tables all contain primary keys in the database and these appear to have been brought through to the edmx as the edmx shows the key symbol by the correct fields and if you view the properties of the fields Entity Key = True. All of the other entity projects work correctly and some of them contain some of the same tables that are causing problems here.

I have deleted some of the offending tables and re-added them, but this didn't help. I am loathed to delete the whole edmx and start again, as it took quite a while to get right and this might not fix the problem.

Can anybody help me with this problem please? Thank you.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the edmx also validates successfully in Visual Studio

Comment: Note that if you're using composite keys with .NET 4.5, you need to use a pre-release version of EF, due to a number of attributes being moved to a different namespace. I got this exact message because EF didn't recognize my composite keys.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume a property Id maps to your primary key, then you have to decorate its property with `[key]` attribute like this:

```
[Key]
public int Id { get; set; }
```